# OpenID based login mechanism for website

Tags: jakarta-ee, authentication, openid

i am working on a login process of our web-portal and in order to give better user experience we have decided to impliment OpenId based login mechanism similar as currently SO is have.

As our application is java/j2ee based with struts2 as MVC frameowrk, i am wordring is there any good open source solution to achieve this functionality.

one such solution which i came acros after doing some googling is

[OpenIdjava](http://code.google.com/p/openid4java/)

i am not sure how much it will be helpful since i have not explored it.My question is are there other open source implimentation which can help us to achieve this.

at initial level we need to impliemtn this functionality for Google,yahoo and AOL users and also for facebook users (fackbook dos not adhere to openID so we have to impliment it in our own way)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a good opensource Java library for OAuth: [scribe-java](https://github.com/fernandezpablo85/scribe-java).

OAuth is a better idea, because it is simplier to use for the end user (he doesn't need to know the OpenId URL, just clicks the button "Sign in with Google" or "Twitter") and allows you not only authenticate the user, but also get his personal data (contacts, calendar, etc.)